# Inheriting from class with type constraints - "There is no implicit reference conversion from..."

Tags: c#, asp.net, types, type-constraints

I have a base class for databinding a single datasource like this:

```
public abstract class DataControlBase<TContainer, TDataType> : Control
    where TDataType : new()
    where TContainer : TemplateContainerBase<TDataType>, new()
{
    public TDataType DataSource { get; set; }
}
```

The container class (TContainer) will always inherit from the container base:

```
public abstract class TemplateContainerBase<TDataType> : Control
    where TDataType : new()
{
    public TemplateContainerBase() { }

    public TDataType DataItem { get; set; }
}
```

Finally I have a repeater base where I will bind several data items as the datasource:

```
public abstract class RepeaterBase<TContainer, TDataType> : DataControlBase<TContainer, List<TDataType>>
    where TDataType : new()
    where TContainer : TemplateContainerBase<TDataType>, new()
{

}
```

I get an error on the RepeaterBase saying this

> Error 1   The type 'TContainer' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContainer' in the generic type or method 'WebTestHarness.Controls.DataControlBase'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'TContainer' to 'WebTestHarness.Controls.TemplateContainerBase>'.

I have read a few different threads describing similar issues but all seem to relate to methods whereas this is solely to do with class design.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
RepeaterBase<TContainer, TDataType> : DataControlBase<TContainer, List<TDataType>>
```

so you've set `List<TDataType>` as the second type parameter `Y` for `DataControlBase<X, Y>`. But your constraint for `DataControlBase` requires that `X : TemplateContainerBase<Y>, new()`. So, in your case, you would need the constraint

```
where TContainer : TemplateContainerBase<List<DataType>>, new()
```

on `TContainer`, not

```
where TContainer : TemplateContainerBase<DataType>, new()
```

as you currently have.

That is, just because you've used the same *names* for the type parameters in the varying classes does not mean that they represent the same types when you start parameterizing things. That is

```
class Foo<A> { }
class Bar<A> : Foo<List<A>> { }
```

The `A` in `Bar` is *not* the same as the `A` in `Foo`. Instead, `List<A>` is playing the role of `A` for `Foo<A>` in the definition of `Bar<A>`.